# Finding next smallest number with same digits

Tags: ruby

I'm working with Ruby and trying to write a code that will take a numerical input and return the next biggest number with the same digits.

I have seen this same question asked here before but the code differs too much to help me solve my particular problem.

```
def next_smaller n
  ndigitsarray=n.digits.reverse
  bigdigitsarray=ndigitsarray.sort.reverse
  bigdigitsjoint=bigdigitsarray.join.to_i
    while bigdigitsjoint>n do 
  bigdigitsarray.insert(1, bigdigitsarray.delete_at(0)) 
    end
  return bigdigitsarray.join.to_i
end
```

The code times out; I am not sure why it isn't looping correctly. Any help would be gratefully received!

EDIT - I have worked out why there is an infinite loop, but I am leaving this up for now in case anyone has any suggestions for solving the larger problem!

Comment: Your solution is wrong because it covers only linear shift of digits and not the permutation(e.g. when two or more digits swap places, not only replace. It won't find the nearest smaller number with same digits, it won't find anything because your joined variable does not change after the first assignment and you check for it in the while condition. It seems like you don't understand the programming that well, so you should better learn it better(like variable assignment concept) before tackling such problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a while loop where the variable used in while condition does not change inside the loop.

One option to solve the problem by brute force is using [Array#permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-permutation) on the [Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-digits) array:

```
n = 1231
n.digits.permutation.uniq.map { |e| e.join.to_i }.sort.keep_if { |k| k > n }.first
#=> 1312
```

It uses [Array#keep_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-keep_if) to keep all the numbers (`k`) bigger than `n`.

It returns `nil` if there is no biggest number.

---

Using [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) you can see "what's inside":

```
n.digits.permutation.uniq.map { |e| e.join.to_i }.sort.partition { |k| k > n }
#=> [[1312, 1321, 2113, 2131, 2311, 3112, 3121, 3211], [1123, 1132, 1213, 1231]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by creating a method whose argument `digits` is an array of digits and which returns a ("counting") hash whose keys are the digits `0-9` and whose values are `digits.count(d)` for each key `d`.

```
def count_digits(digits)
  digits.each_with_object((0..9).to_a.product([0]).to_h) { |d,h| h[d] += 1 }
end
```

For example,

```
digits = 35145.digits
  #=> [5, 4, 1, 5, 3] 
digit_counts = count_digits(digits)
  #=> {0=>0, 1=>1, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>2, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>0}
```

(See [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-product) and [Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits)). We can now write a method that returns the desired result.

```
def next_smallest(n)
  digits = n.digits
  digit_counts = count_digits(digits)
  (n-1).downto(0).find { |m| count_digits(m.digits) == digit_counts }
end
```

```
require 'time'

def doit(n)
  t = Time.now
  n = next_smallest(n)
  puts "Elapsed time in seconds = #{(Time.now-t).round(7)}"
  n
end

doit  44444
  # Elapsed time in seconds = 0.2008061
  #=> nil 
doit  35154
  # Elapsed time in seconds = 5.18e-05
  #=> 35145 
doit  35154217464215716524742391453862
  # Elapsed time in seconds = 0.0005618
  #=> 35154217464215716524742391453826 
doit  351542174642157165247423914538623999
  # Elapsed time in seconds = 3.4207082
  #=> 351542174642157165247423914538399962
```

Though it may be somewhat academic, we can do better. Given `digits` and `digit_counts` above, to update `digits` for

```
n = 35153
```

we may write (because the last digit is greater than zero):

```
digits[0] -= 1
digits
  #=> [4, 4, 1, 5, 3]
```

Similarly, after making a deep copy of `digit_counts`:

```
h = digit_counts.transform_values(&:itself)
  #=> {0=>0, 1=>1, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>2, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>0}
```

we may update this hash by writing:

```
d0 = digits.first
  #=> 4 
h[d0] += 1
h[d0+1] -= 1
h #=> {0=>0, 1=>1, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>2, 5=>1, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>0}
```

rather than calling `count_digits`. (See [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values)). Now let's revise the method as follows.

```
def next_smallest(n)
  digits = n.digits
  digit_counts = count_digits(digits)
  h = digit_counts.transform_values(&:itself)
  (n-1).downto(10).find do |m|
    d0 = digits.first
    if d0 > 0
      digits[0] -= 1
      h[d0] -= 1
      h[d0-1] += 1
    else
      digits = m.digits
      h = count_digits(digits)
    end
    h == digit_counts
  end
end
```

```
doit  44444
  # Elapsed time in seconds = 0.0607323
  #=> nil 
doit  35154
  # Elapsed time in seconds = 0.0001582
  #=> 35145 
doit  35154217464215716524742391453862
  # Elapsed time in seconds = 0.000216
  #=> 35154217464215716524742391453826 
doit  351542174642157165247423914538623999
  # Elapsed time in seconds = 0.5180595
  #=> 351542174642157165247423914538399962
```

Further improvements would be possible in the case where the last digit is zero (to avoid calling `count_digits`). If, for example,

```
n = 2130
digits = n.digits
  #=> [0, 3, 1, 2]
h = count_digits(digits)
  #=> {0=>1, 1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>1, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>0}
```

`digits` and `h` could be updated for `n = 2129` as follows:

```
n -= 1
  #=> 2129
d1 = digits[1] 
  #=> 3 
digits
  #=> [9, 2, 1, 2] 
h[0] -= 1
h[9] += 1
h[d1] -= 1
h[d1-1] += 1
h #=> {0=>0, 1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>1}
```

One could do something similar if `n = 2100` or `2000`, but it quickly becomes faster to just call `count_digits`,

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't tasked with creating the array of numbers yourself, there's an [Array#permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-permutation) method available to generate all the combinations of numbers based on your original number.

Then, after some cleanup & sorting you can find the index of your number and then add 1 to find the next highest number.

```
def next_number(i)
  puts "Your number is #{i}"
  permutations = i.to_s.split('').permutation.to_a.map(&:join).map(&:to_i).uniq.sort
  index = (permutations.find_index(i) + 1)

  puts "Next highest is #{permutations[index]}"
end

# Usage
next_number(4357)
next_number(81541)
```

Caveats:

- Doesn't address if your number is the highest permutation (e.g. `next_number(999)`)
- Probably not the "fastest" way to do this, if it's part of a code challenge

Comment: This is a brute force approach

Comment: @ZiaQamar Yes. There was a legitimate issue with the OPs code that caused an infinite loop even with small integers (like 123) so their code wasn't working at all. This was meant to give them a working example to compare their code against.